# How to get everything before a character and x amount after?

Tags: python, split

It has been trial and error and can't seem to get what I want.

I am accessing an API to get some info. Unfortunately it's the only API to get that info and to do it, it downloads a binary content of a file and names it:

`folder\filename.whatever`
i.e. `test\purpleMonkeyTest.docx`

There is a bunch more info that comes in from the call but there is this line:

```
Saved the binary content to: /home/user/python/test\purpleMonkeyTest.docx
```

Some of the files have `"` or other special characters so I can't just get the file name and delete it as part of the script, since I won't know what to escape.

So my goal here is to strip the line and get:

```
/home/user/python/test\purpleMonkeyTest.docx
```

then get only:

```
/home/user/python/test\pu
```

then:

```
os.remove "/home/user/python/test\pu"*
```

I'm thinking that a wildcard should work for all, unless there is a better way to do it. All files saved have the character `\` in them so I've got to the point where I'm getting everything prior to the `\` but I want one or two characters after that as well.

Here's what I've tried:

```
def fileName(itemID):
    import fnmatch
    details = itemDetails(itemID, True) # get item id and file details
    filepath = matchPattern((details), 'Saved the binary content to: *')
    filepath = (filepath).split('\\')[0]
    print(filepath)
    #os.remove(re.escape(filepath))
    return (matchPattern((details), 'Binary component: *'))


def matchPattern(details, pattern):
    import fnmatch
    return (fnmatch.filter((details), pattern)[0].split(": " ,1)[1])
```

Output:

```
/home/user/python/test
purpleMonkeyTest.docx
```

I do want the file name for later: that's actually the main goal. The API downloads the damn file automatically though.

**EDIT:**

Answer below works for getting the chars I want. Os remove is not removing the file though.

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/python/test\\Re*'
```

Managed to get it to work using glob, I guess os.remove doesn't support Wilds.

```
    files = glob.glob((filepath)+"*")
    for file in files:
     os.remove(file)
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you would like to retrieve 2 parts - everything between first `/` and `\` with 2 chars afterwards and then everything after `\`:

```
str = "Saved the binary content to: /home/user/python/test\purpleMonkeyTest.docx"

print (str[str.index("/"):str.rindex("\\") + 3])
print (str[str.rindex("\\") + 1:])
```

**Output**

> /home/user/python/test\pu
>
> purpleMonkeyTest.docx